# Interpolating irregularly spaced 3D matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, grid, 2d, interpolation

I have a time series of temperature profiles that I want to interpolate, I want to ask how to do this if my data is irregularly spaced.

Here are the specifics of the matrix:

- The temperature is 30x365
- The time is 1x365
- Depth is 30x1

Both time and depth are irregularly spaced. I want to ask how I can interpolate them into a regular grid?

I have looked at `interp2` and `TriScatteredInterp` in Matlab, however the problem are the following:

1. `interp2` works only if data is in a regular grid.
2. `TriscatteredInterp` works only if the vectors are column vectors. Although time and depth are both column vectors, temperature is not.

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply iterate through each row of temperature (`temperature(i, :)`) in order to get around the size problem. However, the question is unclear. What exactly is it that you want to do? What kind of interpolation? Linear, Polynomial, something fancy? Can you not just fit as usual and go from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `Interp2` does not require for a *regularly spaced* measurement grid at all, it only requires a ***monotonic*** one. That is, sampling positions stored in vectors `depths` and `times` must increase (or decrease) and that's all.

Assuming this is indeed is the *situation** and that you want to interpolate at *regular positions*** stored in vectors `rdepths` and `rtimes`, you can do:

```
[JT, JD] = meshgrid(times, depths); %% The irregular measurement grid
[RT, RD] = meshgrid(rtimes, rdepths); %% The regular interpolation grid
TemperaturesOnRegularGrid = interp2(JT, JD, TemperaturesOnIrregularGrid, RT, RD);
```

* *: If not, you can sort on rows and columns to come back to a monotonic grid.

***: *In fact `Interp2` has no restriction for output grid (it can be irregular or even non-monotonic).*

Answer (score 0):

I would use your data to fit to a spline or polynomial and then re-sample at regular intervals.  I would highly recommend the [polyfitn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) function.  Actually, anything by this John D'Errico guy is incredible.  Aside from that, I have used this function in the past when I had data on a irregularly spaced 3D problem and it worked reasonably well.  If your data set has good support, which I suspect it does, this will be a piece of cake.  Enjoy!  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [GridFit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8998) tool on MATLAB central by John D'Errico. To use it, pass in your 2 independent data vectors (time & temperature), the dependent data matrix (depth) along with the regularly spaced X & Y data points to use. By default the tool also does smoothing for overlapping (or nearly) data points. If this is not desired, you can override this (and other options) through a wide range of configuration options. Example code:

```
%Establish regularly spaced points
num_points = 20;
time_pts = linspace(min(time),max(time),num_points);
depth_pts = linspace(min(depth),max(depth),num_points);

%Run interpolation (with smoothing)
Pest = gridfit(depth, time, temp, time_pts, depth_pts);
```